# SQL Server transaction isolation problem - global variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 R2 (Data Center edition - I think)

I have a very specific requirement for the database.

I need to insert a row marked with timestamp `[ChangeTimeStamp]`. Timestamp value is passed as a parameter. Timestamp has to be unique.

Two processes can insert values at the same time, and I happen to run into duplicate key insertion once in a while. To avoid this, I am trying:

```
declare @maxChangeStamp bigint

set transaction isolation level read committed
begin transaction 
select @maxChangeStamp = MAX(MaxChangeTimeStamp) from TSMChangeTimeStamp

if (@maxChangeStamp > @changeTimeStamp)
    set @maxChangeStamp = @maxChangeStamp + 1   
else 
    set @maxChangeStamp = @changeTimeStamp

update TSMChangeTimeStamp 
set MaxChangeTimeStamp = @maxChangeStamp 
commit

set @changeTimeStamp = @maxChangeStamp

insert statment
```

- REPEATABLE READ - causes deadlock
- READ COMMITTED - causes duplicate key inserts

`@changeTimeStamp` is my parameter.
`TSMChangeTimeStamp` holds only one value.

If anyone has a good idea how to solve this I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` does the table only have one row? And if so why are you using `MAX` in the `SELECT` or even using a separate `SELECT` statement at all.

Comment: Where are you getting you TimeStamp from or, how is it being generated? and what is the TSMChangeTimeStamp table?

Comment: Oh, and show us the WHOLE procedure.  Otherwise, there's not much we can do about the deadlocks.

Comment: Do you have a deadlock trace?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx for ways to get more information about this deadlock.

Comment: @Martin - I could use top 1 instead or not use it at all. So you are right. I am modifying statement so it is not final. But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Time stamp is from .Net so it accurate to 100 nanoseconds. TSMChangeTimeStamp holds only one value (kind of a global variable). This is the whole procedure (last stament is just an insert statment).

Comment: @Paul Williams - your answer cleared the deadlock issue. I am performance testing it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the transaction, the SELECT statement will acquire a shared lock if the mode is not READ COMMITTED or snapshot isolation.  If two processes both start the SELECT at the same time, they will both acquire a shared lock.

Later, the UPDATE statement attempts to acquire an exclusive lock (or update lock).  Unfortunately, neither one can acquire an exclusive lock, because the other process has a shared lock.

Try using the [`WITH (UPDLOCK)` table hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) on the SELECT statement.  From MSDN:

> UPDLOCK
>
> Specifies that update locks are to be taken and held until the
>   transaction completes. UPDLOCK takes update locks for read operations
>   only at the row-level or page-level. If UPDLOCK is combined with
>   TABLOCK, or a table-level lock is taken for some other reason, an
>   exclusive (X) lock will be taken instead.
>
> When UPDLOCK is specified, the READCOMMITTED and READCOMMITTEDLOCK
>   isolation level hints are ignored. For example, if the isolation level
>   of the session is set to SERIALIZABLE and a query specifies (UPDLOCK,
>   READCOMMITTED), the READCOMMITTED hint is ignored and the transaction
>   is run using the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.

For example:

```
begin transaction
select @maxChangeStamp = MAX(MaxChangeTimeStamp) from TSMChangeTimeStamp with (updlock)
```

Note that update locks may be promoted to a table lock if there is no index for your table ([Microsoft KB article 179362)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179362).

Explicitly requesting an XLOCK may also work.

Also note your UPDATE statement does not have a WHERE clause.  This causes the UPDATE to lock and update every record in the table (if applicable in your case).

Answer (score 3):

You don't read-increment-update, this will fail no matter what you try. Alway update and use the OUTPUT clause to the new value:

```
update TSMChangeTimeStamp 
   set MaxChangeTimeStamp  += 1
   output inserted.MaxChangeTimeStamp;
```

You can capture the output value if you need it in T-SQL. But although this will do what you're asking, you most definitely do not want to do this, specially on a system that is high end enough to run DC edition. Generating the next timestamp will place an X lock on the timestamp resource, and thus will prevent **every** other transaction from generating a new timestamp until the current transaction commits. You achieve complete serialization of work with only one transaction being active at a moment. The performance will tank to the bottom of the abyss.

You must revisit your requirement and come up with a more appropriate one. As it is now your requirement can also be expressed as 'My system is too fast, how can I make is really really really slow?'.

Comment: I need to handle duplicate key insertions without throwing duplicate key insertion exception back to the user. Do you see other way of doing it? Requirements are not that eccentric - I need to insert a time stamp that has to be unique.

Comment: On the other hand, do you think that selecting single value from one column and one record table, checking one condition, setting one value and updating it back will take up so much time that performance will hit hard?

Comment: read-check-write problem is not performance, is correctness. read with U lock is still incorrect. read with X lock *may* be correct, but it is just a convoluted way to reaching exactly the same restrictions and scalability problems as the update with output. There are plenty of ways to handle duplicate keys w/o throwing errors, why not post a question and ask *that*. There are also ways to generate unique timestamps as `rowversion` type is *designed* for such: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: Very well. Lets post a question about duplicate keys problem handling. Rowversion will not suite my needs, because it changes every time row is updated. But thank you for pointing it out.